# Difference between defining SAS macrovariables via %let and call symput?

Tags: variables, macros, sas, definition

I am not sure what the difference is between

%let m=product and
cal symput('m', 'product')   is?

Aren't both expressions creating af macrovariable, m, which has the value product?

Answer (score 8):

`%let` is used to define a macro variable based on text or an *expression* that resolves to text.  It is called in open code, or in a macro.  `%let` automatically trims the macro variable of both leading and trailing blanks.  Documentation can be found [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000543704.htm).

`call symput` (documentation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000127861.htm)) is used to assign the contents of a SAS dataset variable, an expression that resolves to a SAS dataset variable (or a PDV variable), a character value, or an expression that resolves to a character value (including a numeric value, which resolves to its character equivalent in the default format, normally BEST12.).  `call symput` does *not* trim leading or trailing blanks, so for example the expression

```
%let x=5;
%put [&x];
```

gives you a somewhat different result than the expression

```
data _null_;
call symput('y',5);
run;
%put [&y];
```

`call symputx` (available since 9.2) has more similar results to `%let`, in that it trims leading and trailing blanks.  That is particularly helpful for macro variables created from numbers, as those typically have several leading blanks, like in the above example.

`%let` and `call symput\symputx` also have some differences in scoping.  Both when used in open code (or a data step not in a macro) will place the macro variable in the global table, but `%let` used in a macro will place the variable in the most local table that it exists already, if it does; ie, if you have a `global` variable `&myvar` then `%let myvar=5;` will modify the global variable `&myvar`, not create a locally scoped variable.  `call symput` will place the variable in the most local nonempty symbol table, regardless of whether it exists in a global scope already or not.  `call symputx` will do the same, unless you specify an optional argument indicating which table you wish it to be placed.

Comment: I did the test. It is just nice. Thanks again for that knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is the method for invoking either `%LET` or `call symput`.

`%LET` is used in open code, not inside a datastep or proc.

`call symput` is used inside a datastep, and not in open code.

Answer (score 0):

%let is a macro statement that you can use in open code or inside a macro. Call symptoms can be used only in a DATA step, not in open code. Mind you, this DATA Step may be inside a macro.

As for the scope of the variable created, please see:

http://www.lexjansen.com/phuse/2009/po/PO15.pdf